# C#: Override DataGridView Scrollbars (custom OnPaint)?

Tags: c#, datagridview, overriding, scrollbar, onpaint

I have a usercontrol that inherits from a DataGridView. I have overridden OnRowPrePaint, OnRowPostPaint, OnCellPaint, and some others so I can draw the entire thing as I want. Everything works beautifully, except the scrollbars. How can I intercept the scrollbars being painted and paint my own?

Ideally there is some datastructure that contains the bounds for the scroll bar itself as well as the bounds for actually scroll-slider. Then I can just draw on the graphics layer at those locations.

Is there a way to do this? It seems like everything else was though of, so I would imagine there is some way to do it...

Comment: This is not possible, abandon all hope.

Comment: To add onto what Hans said: there are some hacks (like hiding the default scrollbars and drawing your own), but these are *way* too much work to really ever be justified. Mainly, this was not thought of because the control uses the standard Windows scrollbars, not ones that it draws itself. I agree that you should abandon all hope unless *absolutely necessary*.

Comment: Have to agree with Hans and Cody - world of pain. Probably not a very helpful suggestion, but WPF is *very* good when you need this sort of flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inheriting from the scrollbar class, add this to Sub New:

```
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
```

The OnPaint event will now fire.

To override the standard buttons / slider from being drawn when clicking the control:

```
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse, True)
```

And to reduce the flicker:

```
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, False)
```

EDIT:

I clearly need to learn to read.

Didn't notice the

> usercontrol that inherits from a
>   DataGridView

bit........

Answer (score -1):

First thing that comes to mind: use the paint events from the scrollbars. The scrollbars are derived from `Control` anyway. Might not be the optimum solution...

```
public class MyDGV : DataGridView
{
    this.VerticalScrollBar.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(VerticalScrollBar_Paint);
}

void VerticalScrollBar_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Paint stuff
}
```

Comment: -1 Even after you rewrite this code so that it actually compiles, it still does *nothing*. The scrollbars aren't painted by the `Paint` event, but rather by Windows itself. Have you tried it yourself?